# Date Conversion Django Error

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I have a date here which is `Fri Jun 19 02:27:25 PDT 2015` which I get from the DB and I am trying to convert it from PDT to UTC
For which first I am converting it to a datetime object like this:

```
date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y');
```

When I run the python file directly, it works, but when this code executes thru the Django framework, I get this error.

> ValueError: time data 'Fri Jun 19 02:27:25 PDT 2015' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'

I have a feeling this is because of the timezone, because I have many more date formats which don’t contain timezone and conversion for them works fine. Could you suggest a workaround for this.

Comment: Just like to point out that for me copy pasting the Fri... part into the string date and then trying to run the line shown results in an error for me. So I'm not sure what your doing as far as "run the python file directly" but I'm guessing the string or something in your code is different.

Answer (score 0):

This error raised because `datetime` module not recognize all time-zones, use [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module instead of `datetime` similar below:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('Fri Jun 19 02:27:25 PDT 2015')
```